# What is the definition of "Wohnung" in german law?

Tags: germany, landlord

I live in a room of the house of an old lady, and here I am not allowed to use the kitchen. During certain days I can use the shower and washing machine. However, still I got a "Wohnungsgeberbestätigung", so I want to ask, what does Wohnung mean in German? I thought it meant a whole apartment.

Is a single room without access to other rooms, also a Wohnung?

Comment: You are not allowed to use the shower every day? That seems unreasonable. I suggest you get some advise from your local [Mieterverein](https://mieterbund.de/mieterverein-vor-ort/). Judging by your recent questions you should also look for new accommodation.

Answer (score 5):

*Wohnung* has a different meaning in different contexts. Idiomatically, one would call this *Zimmer* (possibly *möbliertes Zimmer*) *zur Untermiete*.

- For purposes of [Art. 13(1) GG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/gg/art_13.html), this would be your *Wohnung*.
- For purposes of the Berlin [Wohnungsaufsichtsgesetz](https://gesetze.berlin.de/bsbe/document/jlr-WoAufGBEpG1/part/X), such a *Zimmer* would be insufficient to count as a *Wohnung*. But then, you are not the *Hauptmieter*, right?
  *Addition by Kai Burghardt: For purposes of building codes, *Wohnung* is a living room (i. e. at least one window to the outside) plus a bathroom (toilet and at least a shower) and an identifiable cooking area (kitchenette sufficient), that has lockable door(s) leading to outdoors or one intermediate staircase/hallway. The exact details depend on state law.*
- For purposes of the [Bundesmeldegesetz §20](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bmg/__20.html), it is your *Wohnung*.

A couple of years ago, something like one percent of *Wohnungen* in Germany did lack their own toilet (i.e. the toilet was outside the dwelling, possibly shared).

Answer (score 4):

> Is a single room without access to other rooms, also a Wohnung?

Yes, since it is a **closed space used for living or sleeping**.

---

A **Wohnungsgeberbestätigung** is part of the Federal Act on Registration (§19).

What a **Wohnung** [Residence] is is defined in §20

- [§20 - Definition of residence [Begriff der Wohnung] - Federal Act on Registration](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bmg/englisch_bmg.html#p0212):

> A residence as defined in this Act is any closed space used for living or sleeping. ...